# Хранение данных в MySQL за определенный период

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Имеется таблица в MySQL в которой постоянно будут добавляться новые записи.Так вот,стоит задача хранить записи только за последний месяц.Я так понимаю,что тут не обойдется без использования триггеров.Подскажите,как реализовать подобную функциональность.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать периодическую операцию, которая раз в сутки будет удалять все данные, которые в последний раз обновлялись раньше, чем месяц назад. Соответственно, таблица должна содержать колонку, по которой будут отбираться старые записи.

Answer (score 2):

Или посмотреть в сторону [партиционирования](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/05/06/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86/).

> Именно на этот вариант стоит
> посмотреть сперва. Партиционирование
> (partitioning) - это разбиение больших
> таблиц на логические части по
> выбранным критериям. Звучит сложно, но
> на практике все просто.
>
> Скорее всего у Вас есть несколько
> огромных таблиц (обычно всю нагрузку
> обеспечивают всего несколько таблиц
> СУБД из всех имеющихся). Причем чтение
> в большинстве случаев приходится
> только на самую последнюю их часть
> (т.е. активно читаются те данные,
> которые недавно появились). Примером
> тому может служить блог - на первую
> страницу (это последние 5…10 постов)
> приходится 40…50% всей нагрузки, или
> новостной портал (суть одна и та же),
> или системы личных сообщений… впрочем
> понятно. Партиционирование таблицы
> позволяет базе данных делать
> интеллектуальную выборку - сначала
> СУБД уточнит, какой партиции
> соответствует Ваш запрос (если это
> реально) и только потом сделает этот
> запрос, применительно к нужной
> партиции (или нескольким партициям).
> Таким образом, в рассмотренном случае,
> Вы распределите нагрузку на таблицу по
> ее партициям. Следовательно выборка
> типа “SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY
> id DESC LIMIT 10” будет выполняться
> только над последней партицией,
> которая значительно меньше всей
> таблицы.